# Is there a neater way than to repeat a function 3 times for 3 same actions?

Tags: jquery

Basically I am doing something similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/71/

Except I have 3 instances of these, all with the same function required for each button. And there's no back button/link to return it to its normal state.

So i've labeled each insance with its own unique id's for the relavant parts and the following jquery:

```
    $('#btn0').click(function(e){    
            $('#btn0').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#reveal0').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
        $('#btn1').click(function(e){    
            $('#btn1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#reveal1').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
        $('#btn2').click(function(e){    
            $('#btn2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#reveal2').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
```

It just seems a bit clunky this way and was wandering if theres neater syntax to do this? I've tried .each and listing them all in one function but they all fade together then which isn't what i want. Thanks

Comment: What about using a method?

Comment: Yes, replace your differing id's with identical classes, then select the fadeIn target based on the clicked button's location in the DOM or it's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delegate the event click from a parent container, and retreive the id of the element to reveal via a data attribute on the tag targetted by the click .

Something like that :

```
$('.btn-container').on('click', '.btn', function(e){
  var $toReveal = $("#" + $(this).data('reveal-id'))
  $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $toReveal.fadeIn('slow')
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn0, #btn1, #btn2').click(function(e){    
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#reveal' + this.id.replace('btn','')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
 });
```

It would make more sense to use a class and a data attribute:

```
<button class="mybutton" data-reveal="reveal0">Foo</button>
<button class="mybutton" data-reveal="reveal1">Bar</button>
```

And then:

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#' + $this.data('reveal')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can have multiple buttons with one event handler.  Then just get the sender:

```
$(function() { 

  $('#<%=btn1.ClientID %>, #<%=btn2.ClientID %>').click(function(event) { 
     var getBtnId= $(event.target).attr('id');
      'then just do some code specific to the button ID

    }); 
});
```

Comment: `var getBtnId= $(event.target).attr('id');` can be referenced as `this.id`